# Twitter Bootstrap scrollspy in menu

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I had a menu with links into another pages (with same menu) Now I add scrollspy on home page and add sections from home page into menu. Now my menu looks like:

```
<li class=""><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="/home/#foo">Foo</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="/home/#boo">Boo</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="/moo">Moo</a></li>
```

But scrollspy doesn't work. When I remove "/home/" from section links scrollspy works but menu works only on home page. Is possible do what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is check on server side whether I am on a home page and If not I am adding /home before section part.
So my code now looks like:

```
<li class=""><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="@if(section.contains("home")){#foo} else{/home/{#foo}">Foo</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="@if(section.contains("home")){#boo} else{/home/{#boo}">Boo</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="/moo">Moo</a></li>
```

Code for server side is in scala (I am using play framework) but in php and whatever else it would be similar.